# Populate new column in dataframe based on dictionary key matches values in another column and some more conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like

[image: Dataframe]

I have a dictionary with the ec2 instance details

[image: Dictionary]

Now, I want to add a new column 'Instance Name' and populate it based on a condition that the instance ID in the dictionary is in the column 'ResourceId' and further, depending on what is there in the Name field in dictionary for that instance Id, I want to populate the new column value for each matching entry

[image: New Column]

Finally I want to create separate data frames for my specific use-cases e.g. to get only Box-Usage results. Something like this

```
box_usage = df[df['lineItem/UsageType'].str.contains('BoxUsage')]
print(box_usage.groupby('Instance Name')['lineItem/BlendedCost'].sum())
```

The new column value is not coming up against the respective Resource Id as I desire. It is rather coming up sequentially.
I have tried bunch of things including what I mentioned in above code, but no result yet. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling through several options, I used the ***.apply()*** way and it did the trick

```
df.insert(loc=17, column='Instance_Name', value='Other')
instance_id = []

def update_col(x):
    for key, val in ec2info.items():
        if x == key:
            if ('MyAgg' in val['Name']) | ('MyAgg-AutoScalingGroup' in val['Name']):
                return 'SharkAggregator'
            if ('MyColl AS Group' in val['Name']) | ('MyCollector-AutoScalingGroup' in val['Name']):
                return 'SharkCollector'
            if ('MyMetric AS Group' in val['Name']) | ('MyMetric-AutoScalingGroup' in val['Name']):
                return 'Metric'

df['Instance_Name'] = df.ResourceId.apply(update_col)
df.Instance_Name.fillna(value='Other', inplace=True)
```